# Calculate the limit $\lim_{X\to-1}\frac{X}{(X+1)^2}=?$

Tags: limits

$$\displaystyle\lim_{X\to-1}\frac{X}{(X+1)^2}=?$$

How to calculate the limit of this function?

Comment: Where are stuck at?

Comment: I know the limit is −∞ by drawing a graph. However, our teacher asks us to calculate the limit, and I am not allowed to use the graph to explain why the limit is negative infinity

Comment: I'd be satisfied if the student says that the denominator has limit $0$ by positive values, whereas the numerator has limit $-1$, so the limit of the quotient is $-\infty$.

Comment: I'm really confused because I think -1/0 should be undefined instead of being negative infinity.

Comment: $\frac{-1}{0}$ is undefined. But $\frac{-1}{10^{-n}} = -10^{n}$ is well-defined for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So as $n \to \infty$, we have $\frac{-1}{10^{-n}} \to - \infty$.

Comment: @FlyingBirds The key is that (roughly and informally speaking) it is $-1/0^+$, *not* $-1/0$. I.e., the denominator goes to $0$, but only taking *positive* values.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how your teacher wants you to compute this limit. There are some general criteria for cases like these. The main one can be stated as follows:

> Suppose $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}f(x)=k\ne0$ and $\lim_{x\to a^+}g(x)=0$, with $g(x)>0$ for $0a<x<a+\tau$, for some $\tau>0$. Then
>   $$
> \lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=
> \begin{cases}
> \infty & \text{if $k>0$}\\
> -\infty & \text{if $k<0$}
> \end{cases}
> $$

If in the statement you change the $g(x)>0$ condition into $g(x)<0$, then the limits are swapped. Similarly for limits from the left, of course, with just a small change that you can work out.

Here's a proof of the statement, for the case $k>0$. Let $M>0$; we need to find $\delta>0$ such that, for $a<x<a+\delta$,
$$
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}>M
$$
By hypothesis, we can find $\delta>0$ such that

1. for $a<x<a+\delta$, $|f(x)-k|<k/2$,
2. for $a<x<a+\delta$, $|g(x)|<k/(2M)$,
3. $\delta\le\tau$.

In particular, for $a<x<a+\delta$, $f(x)-k>-k/2$, so $f(x)>k/2$; also $0<g(x)<k/(2M)$, so
$$
\frac{1}{g(x)}>\frac{2M}{k}
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}>\frac{2M}{k}\frac{k}{2}=M
$$

---

The criterion can be applied to your case, because $(1+x)^2>0$ for $x\ne-1$ and $\lim_{x\to-1}x=-1$. Thus
$$
\lim_{x\to-1^+}\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}=
\lim_{x\to-1^-}\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}=-\infty
$$
and so
$$
\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}=-\infty
$$

Comment: Thank you so much..Although I don't think my teacher requires that detail-oriented proof, it really reinforces my understanding of the limits!

Comment: @FlyingBirds I bet your teacher doesn't want that proof each time! After having proved a powerful theorem, you can apply it whenever its hypotheses are satisfied.

Comment: But I'm confused why you don't have to choose Min (δ1,δ2). It seems that you use only one δ here, and I don't understand why δ falls in the same range for different functions

Comment: @FlyingBirds I did it implicitly: there's a $\delta_1$ for condition 1, $\delta_2$ for condition 2, and you can take $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2,\tau)$, so all three conditions are satisfied with respect to the same $\delta$.

Comment: Okay. In addition, when it comes to f(x)g(x)>2Mk2=M, I'm confused how you cancel the "K"

Comment: @FlyingBirds Sorry, forgot a $k$: I'll fix it in a moment.

Comment: Now it makes sense! Thanks!